# How do I redirect to a different Razor page without page name string?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

In my ASP.NET Razor Pages application the user often has to click on a button and becomes redirected to a different (internal) page of the application. To keep the code maintainable I want to avoid using a string for the page name. Is there a way I could get the page name from a static property or class name?

```
public class SomeModel : PageModel
{
    public ActionResult OnPostLogin()
    {
    // Don't want to use string because it's hard to maintain!
    //   return new RedirectResult("AnotherPage");

    // The below is giving a compile error
    // return new RedirectResult(nameof(_Pages_AnotherPage));
    
    // How to get page name directly from class or property?
       return new RedirectResult(AnotherPage....);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url from appsettings.json.Here is a demo worked:

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "RedirectUrl": "Index"
}
```

cshtml.cs:

```
public class RedirectPageModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public RedirectPageModel(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }
        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            var redirectUrl = _configuration["RedirectUrl"];
            return Redirect(redirectUrl);
        }
    }
```

result:
[image]